# Create Elixir Connection Bash Script

Tags: bash, elixir

I am using one connection library to connect my Elixir shell to ActiveMQ and subscribing to the queues like below and is working well

```
iex --erl "-pa ebin -env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH ./priv -env LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./priv -s qpidpn start"
:qpidpn.subscribe('amqp://127.0.0.1/queue://test')
```

Can someone suggest me, how to create new Elixir Mix application [i mean new module in application: bash script but not from shell] which will do that same thing. That means.

1. Start of qpidpn first.
2. Queue subscription to echo messages coming in queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way would be to use a release for this. Take a look at [exrm](https://github.com/bitwalker/exrm). Basically, you build the release with `mix release`, then run your app using `rel/qpidpn/bin/qpidpn start`. You can then connect to the node using iex with `rel/qpidpn/bin/qpidpn remote_console`, and queue a subscription with `:qpidpn.subscribe('amqp://127.0.0.1/queue://test')`. You can then quit the remote shell session, and your app will continue running indefinitely in the background.